# Every linear differential equation with polynomial coefficients $L(y)=t^n$ has a polynomial solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Every linear differential equation with polynomial coefficients  $L(y)=t^n$ has at least a (particular) polynomial solution. Firstly, I believe that this is true because the linear dif. eq. has polynomial coefficients. The way that I should explain this, it's like the next example.
The linear dif.eq $ 2y''+t^2y'-2ty=t^2$ has the polynomial solution $y=-t$ and if I want to find out why, I must let $y=at+b$. The form of the polynomial solution every time, depends on what polynomial is every coefficient. Am I right?

Comment: If your differential operator is homogeneous, the particular solution should be a power of $t$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams : "Power of $t$" is too much to hope for.  Consider $y'' + y = t^3$, which has the particular solution $t^3 - 6t$.

Comment: This sounds like a piece of [the method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients).

Comment: @EricTowers Ah I meant $L$ needs to play nicely with dilations. Maybe that wasn't clear.

Comment: @CameronWilliams : The differential operator $y \mapsto y''+y$ is homogeneous and "plays nicely with dilations" having degree of homogeneity $1$.

Comment: @EricTowers Ah I see what you mean. That's not quite what I meant since $(y(at))'' = a^2 y''(at) $ but you don't get an $a^2$ on the other term. There's probably better terminology than what I'm using but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @CameronWilliams : I'd probably say "$L(y(t))$ is not homogeneous in $t$."